# Explanation for part of least cost method in c++

Tags: c++, optimization

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
int c[20][20],
i,j, 
min, m, n, b, d, c2, c1, p, q;
int dem[20],sup[20],rf[20],cf[20],sum=0;


  cout<<"\n number of Row: ";
  cin>>m;
  cout<<"\n number of columns: ";
  cin>>n;


  cout<<"\n Cost: \n";         //matrix
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
            cout<<" Cost Matrix : "<<(i+1)<<(j+1);
            cin>>c[i][j];
        }
    }


  cout<<"\n  Demand: \n";
  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
  cout<<" Demand [ : "<<(i+1);
   cin>>dem[i];
  }

  cout<<"\n Supply: \n";
  for(i=0; i<m; i++){ //
  cout<<" Supply  : "<<(i+1);
   cin>>sup[i];
  }

  cout<<"\n Matrix:\n";
  for(i=0; i<m; i++){
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        cout<<" %d | "<<c[i][j];
        cout<<"%d  "<<sup[i];
        cout<<"\n";
    }
  for(j=0; j<n; j++)
   cout<<"%d  "<<dem[j];



  for(i=0; i<m; i++)
   rf[i]=0;
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   cf[i]=0;
  b=m;
  d=n;


  while(b>0 && d>0)
  { min=1000;
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    { if(rf[i]!=1)
      { for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    { if(cf[j]!=1)
      { if(min>c[i][j])
        { min=c[i][j];
           p=i;
           q=j;
        }
      }
    }
      }
    }
    if(sup[p] < dem[q])
     c1=sup[p];
    else
     c1=dem[q];



    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    { if(rf[i]!=1)
      { for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    { if(cf[j]!=1)

{ if(min==c[i][j])
        { if(sup[i]<dem[j])
           c2=sup[i];
          else
           c2=dem[j];

          if(c2>c1)
          { c1=c2;
        p=i;
        q=j;
          }
        }
      }
    }
      }
    }
    //cout<<"\n  %d %d %d ",min,p,q);
    if(sup[p]<dem[q])
    { sum+=c[p][q]*sup[p];
      dem[q]-=sup[p];
      rf[p]=1;
      b--;
    }
    else
    if(sup[p]>dem[q])
    { sum=sum+c[p][q]*dem[q];
      sup[p]-=dem[q];
      cf[q]=1;
      d--;
    }
    else
    if(sup[p]==dem[q])
    { sum=sum+c[p][q]*sup[p];
      rf[p]=1;
      cf[q]=1;
      b--;
      d--;
    }

    //cout<<"\n %d",sum);
  }
  cout<<"\n\n total cost %d\n\n"<<sum;
  system("pause");
}
```

This code is for the least cost method. I don't understand what is the job of `rf[i]` and `cf[i]` and why is `rf[i]!=1`

Least Cost Method steps:

1. Determine the least cost among all the rows of the transportation table.
2. Identify the row and allocate the maximum feasible quantity in the cell corresponding to the least cost in the row. Then eliminate that row (column) when an allocation is made.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for the reduced transportation table until all the available quantities are distributed to the required places. If the minimum cost is not unique, the tie can be broken arbitrarily.

example in two pictures:
[first table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV9Mb.png)

[last table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONDHa.png)

The cost of the allocation by the least cost method is 35 x 5 + 35 x 7 + 30 x 4 + 7 x 7 + 43 x 7 = 890

Answer (score 0):

thats mean if rf[i]=0 is false.

rf[p]=1 mean row is true or cant run in this code 
so the row is deleted. understand??